# Symfony2 > from windows to linux: routes don't work anymore

Tags: symfony, routes

I've recently install a lamp on fedora 18 and Symfony2. Then I exported my bundles and the routing files.

It appears my routes don't work anymore.

this is the address I'd like to access:

```
 http://localhost/Symfony2/web/app_dev.php/chartofaccounts
```

and it gets me: No route found for "GET /chartofaccounts"

in app/config
routing_dev.yml

```
_main:
resource: routing.yml
```

routing.yml

```
nrtworks_chartofaccounts:
resource: "@NRtworksChartOfAccountsBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix: /
```

and in that bundle's routing file:

```
NRtworks_chartofaccounts:
pattern:  /chartofaccounts
defaults: { _controller: NRtworksChartOfAccountsBundle:ChartOfAccounts:index }
```

I've tried path instead of pattern (by the way what's the difference?).

When I run php app/console router:debug I have no route defined for /chartofaccounts
One strange thing, if I delete the /demo route from routing_dev.yml, it still works.

Is there something I'm missing or something different in a unix system (the bundle seems correctly loaded so i guess there is no path issue) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you remove your cache (`php app/console cache:clear`) - if you remove a route and it still works then this sounds very much like caching.

With regards to the `path` vs `pattern` question - from the [Routing Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html)

> New in version 2.2: The path option is new in Symfony2.2, pattern is used in older versions.

Comment: right I had emptied the cache before but it did not actually work because FOSuserbundle was not correctly set up. I did it again and saw the error...

I was right to move to linux: page generation 160 ms vs 800ms on windows

thanks